# How to check if there's an element at a specific position of a grid, or not?

Tags: javascript, css, grid, css-grid

Let's say we have a grid with 5 columns, and 3 rows for an example. But with unknown number of elements, at unknown position.

[image: from css-tricks.com]

Let's say that the only element in grid is the red area. I need a function which has two properties, name them `row, column`, and they mean the coordinates of the grid. So if we set them `1, 3`, the function must return false, because there aren't any elements in the grid. But if we set them `3, 4`, the function must return true. I just need to check if any element have start points in the specified coordinates, but i think it will be more useful if the function can check if the grid contains (any element covers the point) any element at the coordinates. It's possible? (with pure javascript)

Comment: We'd need to know the HTML markup of your grid to really be able to help you.

Comment: I create the grid's rows, and columns, and the elements parameters too in react, with an automated algorithm. I didn't thought that the HTML markup is important, because i want to create a function which works with all kinds of grids, and grid items.

Comment: Well, generally speaking, we'd need to know what types of HTML is output. Is it 12 potentially empty divs inside a `display: grid` container all set to `grid-column: auto / span 3;`? That's easy. Is it masonry style where the elements are positioned with fixed/absolute positioning? That's harder. Output absolutely is important to determine how the function would work

Answer (score 1):

Add ID to all of elements, like this id="12"(1st row, second col).
Use "for" and "if" inside.

Comment: Adding an ID to all elements is a very clever and simple solution; I will be using this.

Answer (score 0):

Get the HTML element and its parents. Then search their positions at the table rows and cols collection and compare them against the row and col given.

```js
function search(row, col){
    var elem = table.querySelector("tag name or element's identifier"),
        parentCol = elem.parentNode,
        parentRow = parentCol.parentNode,
        rowsCollection = table.querySelectorAll("tr"),
        realRowIndex = [].indexOf.call(rowsCollection, parentRow),
        realColIndex = [].indexOf.call(rowsCollection[realRowIndex].querySelectorAll("td"), parentCol);
        
    return row == realRowIndex && col == realColIndex;
}

console.log(search(2, 3)); //true
```

Comment: This would not work for a css grid layout (display:grid) since rows/columns are not HTML tags but areas set from a template. (grid-template-rows & grid-template-columns ) :( The op should provide its HTML/CSS and attempts ;)

Comment: Good point. I really thought he was talking about an HTML table.